# Count all terms in query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there posiibility to find count for every term in query?

Eg. I have following statement to count:

```
(age == 20 || age == 30) && gender == 'male'
```

And I would like to return overall count + subcounts for all terms using single rest call.

Expected count results:

1. `age == 20`
2. `age == 30`
3. `age == 20 || age == 30`
4. `gender == 'male'`
5. `(age == 20 || age == 30) && gender == 'male'`

Example search query built for this specific scenario:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "age": { "value": 20,"boost": 1 } // count 1
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "age": { "value": 30,"boost": 1 } // count 2
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true, "boost": 1
          } // count 3
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "gender.keyword": { "value": "male", "boost": 1 } // count 4
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    } // count 5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to count arbitrary conditionals**

Per your comment, if your goal is to be able to count arbitrary conditions within the result set, you can use a [Filters Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html).  This works by letting you define use queries to define what to count for a each bucket in an aggregation result.  This requires you to write a query for each possible combination you want to capture.  If you would need to figure out all combinations, then you are probably better off returning the individual bucket counts and doing the math yourself like in the original solution below.  For your case it would look something like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "conditions": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "age == 20": {"term": {"age": 20}},
          "age == 30": {"term": {"age": 30}},
          "age == 20 || age == 30": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {"term": {"age": 20}},
                {"term": {"age": 30}}
              ]
            }
          },
          "gender == male": {"term": {"gender.keyword": "male"}},
          "(age == 20 || age == 30) && gender == 'male'": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {"term": {"gender.keyword": "male"}}
              ],
              "should": [
                {"term": {"age": 20}},
                {"term": {"age": 30}}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Giving your this result:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "conditions": {
      "buckets": {
        "(age == 20 || age == 30) && gender == 'male'": {
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        "age == 20": {
          "doc_count": 8
        },
        "age == 20 || age == 30": {
          "doc_count": 19
        },
        "age == 30": {
          "doc_count": 11
        },
        "gender == male": {
          "doc_count": 12
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT: Original answer that didn't handle (A || B) correctly**

The feature you are looking for is called Aggregations, and specifically a [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).  Terms aggregations will count the number of documents for each possible value of a field in the result set matching your query clause.  You can also nest aggregations.  So in the example below, Elasticearch would find all of the documents matching your query, then count how many documents match each age (20, 30, etc), and then for each age count how many documents match each gender.  You could then do the math to compute the different combinations you requested.

Your query would look something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    ...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "age": {
      "terms": {"field": "age"},
      "aggs": {
        "gender": {
          "terms": {"field": "gender"}
        }
      }
    },
    "gender_total": {"terms": {"field": "gender"}}
  }
}
```

The result would look something like this:

```
{
  "hits": { ... },
  "aggregations": {
    "gender_total": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "male",
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        {
          "key": "female",
          "doc_count": 7
        }
      ]
    },
    "age": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 30,
          "doc_count": 11,
          "gender": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "male",
                "doc_count": 9
              },
              {
                "key": "female",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 20,
          "doc_count": 8,
          "gender": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "female",
                "doc_count": 5
              },
              {
                "key": "male",
                "doc_count": 3
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, for example to compute the count for `(age == 20 || age == 30) && gender == 'male'`, you could do something like this python psuedo-code:

```py
# Pull out the bucket objects for each aggregation
age_buckets = result['aggregations']['age']['buckets']
gender_buckets = result['aggregations']['gender_total']['buckets']

# Get the bucket values we care about
age_20 = [b for b in age_buckets if b['key'] == 20][0]
age_30 = [b for b in age_buckets if b['key'] == 30][0]
male = [b for b in gender_buckets if b['key'] == 'male'][0]

# Get the sub-buckets
age_20_male = [b for b in age_20['gender']['buckets'] if b['key'] == 'male'][0]
age_30_male = [b for b in age_30['gender']['buckets'] if b['key'] == 'male'][0]

# age == 20
count_1 = age_20['doc_count']

# age == 30
count_2 = age_30['doc_count']

# age == 20 || age == 30
count_3 = count_1 + count_2

# gender == 'male'
count_4 = male['doc_count']

# (age == 20 || age == 30) && gender == 'male'
count = age_20_male['doc_count'] + age_30_male['doc_count']
```

Comment: These aggregations are pretty useful but I think they don't suite my scenario. As far as I understand there is no possibility to fast count an `OR` stmt. For example, in case I have `age>30 OR expirience>10` condition instead - I would have to implement an n^2 loop to find the real count because some rows may fulfill both conditions and they shouldn't be counted twice. I know that this is possible but with more complex case probably using several queries to elastic search for each possible scenario will be faster than counting by myself.

Comment: I think the code I posted originally will work for the conditions you listed in your original question.  But I will update with a way to count arbitrary conditions.

Comment: It won't. For example you have following set `[<a,b,c>, <a>, <b>]` and you are looking for count of elements which contain `a || b`: In your solution, the result will be `4` because the count of a==2 and count of b==2 as well, but the real value is `3` because 1 item contains both values.

Comment: Yeah, true.  I suppose I assumed you wouldn't have multiple "age" or "gender" values.  Regardless, the filter agg approach should work assuming you define all the clauses you want.